# PHP AJAX success value empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been having trouble with AJAX requests giving blank responses. Minimal version of the problem:

test.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function request() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'info': 'thing'},
            success: function(response)
            {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<button onclick="request();">TEST</button>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
$info = 'nope';
if(isset($_POST['info'])) $info = $_POST['info'];

return $info;
```

When I press the button the alert box is simply blank.

Comment: it should be: data: {info: 'thing'},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.php` doesn't output anything.  Replace this:

```
return $info;
```

with this:

```
echo $info;
```